# what is "No match." in .name whois?

Tags: dns

i'm trying to register the "zilberman.name" domain name and i get contradictory results.

some websites say that the domain is available:
http://whois.domaintools.com/zilberman.name

and some websites say that the domain is taken:
name.com

The whois say: No match.

so, the domain is already taken or not?

Answer (score 1):

The `zilberman.name` domain is likely to be available (whois Linux).

In doubt, and to be sure, try to reserve it via a *registrar* it'll tell you if it is really available.

But you should **hurry**!

Many people read SO, and you never know what some people may do when reading your question...

**edit**

Next time, try the whois, if "No match", then find a registrar and reserve it asap.

Do not post a question relative to a domain on the Net, as some people, in the hope of making a few $$, may be happy to spend 10$ to get it before you :-)

Maybe you could try `firstname-zilberman.name` ?

Comment: so in wich website i can register the domain?

Comment: This link gives `.name` registrars http://verisigninc.com/en_US/products-and-services/domain-name-services/find-registrar/index.xhtml

Comment: gandi.net say: Already taken. godaddy.com, register.com and register.com - don't register .name

Comment: There was also http://www.ntchosting.com/domains/name.html If the domain is already take, it was possibly reserved after your question was posted...

Comment: ntchosting.com say only Transfer - not available:) - other websites still say it is available

Comment: the domain was not registered after the post! no one can register it just like me:). i only want it for email. so firstname@firstname-lastname.name is no so good as firstname@lastname.name:(

Answer (score 0):

.name doesn't work like that. It only allows third level registrations, so you can register john.smith.name, but not smith.name.

Comment: Forgot to mention why you would be seeing 'No match' rather than 'Not available for second level registration': it's likely they haven't had any domain registrations using that surname before, which is why you're getting the peculiar response.

Comment: not true. you can register both second-level and third-level -according to wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.name)